# how to add ipv6 to an apache vhost with v4 https and http

Tags: apache, ipv6, vhosts

I'm having some difficulties with adding ipv6 to a vhost configuration that uses https and http, and forwards all http requests to https. This is what I currently have which works fine, but I'm not sure how to go about adding ipv6 to the mix. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<VirtualHost 213.138.102.25:443>
                ServerName example.co.uk
                ServerAlias www.example.co.uk
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile /home/example/ssl/www_example_co_uk.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/example/ssl/www.example.co.uk.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /home/example/ssl/www_example_co_uk.ca-bundle
                DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html/example.co.uk
                <Directory /home/example/public_html/example.co.uk/>
                    Options MultiViews Indexes FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride all
                </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

     <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName example.co.uk
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk [NC,OR]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.co.uk [NC]
            #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
            Redirect permanent / https://www.example.co.uk/
    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you will need to do;

First, you may need to add a "Listen" directive in your conf file like this

```
Listen [2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652]:443
Listen [2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652]:80
```

Look in your existing conf file for the IP4 version and put it near that.

This might not be necessary if you are just listening to the ports like this

```
Listen 80
```

but if its like this you do need to add it
    Listen 12.34.56.78:80

Second Leave your IP4 directives in-place and copy / paste them replacing the opening section in the copied version with something like this;

```
<VirtualHost [2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652]:443>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost [2001:cdba:0000:0000:0000:0000:3257:9652]:80>
```

Do note that the IPV6 address is enclosed in square brackets and the address provided is only for example.

You will also need to be aware that IPV6 usually has its own firewall/iptables config and there may be other gotchas as well.

Dont forget to reload / restart Apache

Hope this helps.

Comment: @SanderSteffann How did that `☺` end up in your comment? Was something else supposed to have been written there?

Comment: Hehe, smartphone keyboards trying to be smart :)  It should just be `:80`. Will fix!

Comment: Don't copy and paste the whole virtualhost block, just add the addresses to the opening line like: `<virtualhost 192.0.2.1:80 [2001:db8::1]:80>` etc